# Wamp Server 2.2 not working after enabling a PHP Extension

Tags: php, apache, wampserver, php-extension

I've been working on Wamp Server 2.2 . Everything is ok but when I tried to enable a PHP Extension from the icon tray then Apache won't work anymore. Unless I re-install it then it will work. But I need to enable some PHP Extensions like curl and postgre pdo for my project.

I also tried manually editing the php.ini to enable php extensions, still wamp server apache won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What does wont work mean? did you try restarting wamp server after enabling extensions in php.ini ?

Comment: yes, I tried restarting it and won't work. the icon is orange. mysql works fine but apache won't.

Comment: make sure other programs like skype, are not running or on a different port. I always have to start wamp before skype.

Comment: Yes Sir, I don;t have skype either and no other programs is using port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Just enabling a php extension from wamp does not work sometimes because if there is no extension for that module in the php's extension folder then wamp will either stop working or might give out some windows pop up error message when you start wamp.
So please check if those modules exists in the extension directory of your php's root folder.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the info sir but all modules is existing in the extensions folder.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca, did you check your apache server log file?

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer has more than one php.ini file and it is easy for beginners to get confused.

The safest way to edit the **Correct** php.ini file is to use the wampmanager.exe menu links

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This will edit the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin\php.ini` file, which is the correct one for effecting php changes for the PHP used on your web site.

The menu links should also work to activate/deactivate PHP extensions as follows :-

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> click an extension
```

If the extension has a TICK then it is activated, if not then it is not activated. Each time you click on an extensions name, it will restart Apache to action the activation or deactivation of that extension, so give it a few seconds to complete this restart before checking it worked.

There is also a php.ini file in the `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}` folder, however this file is only used by the PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface ) so if you chnage this it will have no effect on the php used by Apache.